# Cookies not set in Firefox

Tags: php, session, firefox, cookies

I've written a php page that is renewing cookies every time a page is load in a session.
So my script receive the cookie, open the session, verify the user, change the SSID and send back the cookie to the browser.
Everything goes well, except when sometimes Firefox randomly do not update the cookies.
Here is the network log debugging the page:

### Page X load:

Cookies en respuesta (RESPONSE)
H
value   s00s3lm7cic5mndom47kfaqgk7
expires 2018-11-16T12:10:40.000Z

G
value   b8b1ebced9011ef91ffa6f6186c776f4682de752
expires 2018-11-16T12:10:40.000Z

Cookies en pedido (REQUEST)
H
7d9qije7kv4rgl9lk5ilg0j3n2

G
0ca359eeef8403856966508dfe42a7d2adb50d7c

### NEXT PAGE LOAD:

Cookies en pedido (REQUEST)
H
1t51hd187gf104qtq12680er47

Obviously, with that cookies the session is not the same... so the user has to login again

I've checked deep inside, and I found that inmediately after get page X, the next request to the server is JS file with .php extension (I really need to pre-process the javascript) but this time no cookies were sent in this request, so I asume that Firefox deleted ALL cookies after page X loaded. But Why? The expiration date is in 2018... any ideas?

Comment: Your changing the session id on every request? Why? That is asking for trouble, race conditions will occur quite easily.

Comment: what do you mean with race conditions?

Comment: Well that the client might be making a new request for whatever resource with an “old” session id, because the new one set in response to a previous request has not arrived yet ... Don’t change the session id on every request, that is just nonsense.

Comment: I was reading about it and I think that was the problem, thanks!